# facing issue when using JDBC in Tomcat 7 with Struts

Tags: mysql, jdbc, struts2, tomcat7

I am developing a web application using Struts 2 where I am trying to insert some values into my local MySQL database.

The code for connecting and accessing database works fine in console application.

But its giving `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` exception when I  run the same code in Struts.

```
Connection conn = null;
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
          String dbName = "testdatabase";
          String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
          try
            {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,"root","root");

                Statement statement=conn.createStatement();
                System.out.println("HelloWorld.execute()");
                int i= statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO testTable VALUES('15','Lucky')");
                System.out.println("res: "+i);

            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            //setMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means it cant find the JDBC driver on your classpath. Do you have the JDBC driver? You need to have the MySQL JDBC drivers. If you dont have it, it can be downloaded from the MySQL website.

If you do have the driver or have downloaded it, make sure it is in the correct place. It needs to be placed on your classpath. This usually means one of two places

1. With your Struts application under the `WEB-INF/lib` folder
2. With the application server. For tomcat this is usually in `<TOMCAT FOLDER>/lib`

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Download jdbc driver and unpack jar under tomcat lib directory